# How can you add multiple default values to a SelectList in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a DropDownList that is populated as so:

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => ModelValue, new SelectList(Model.DefaultValues), Model.EditValues[0])
```

so `Model.EditValues[0]` will assign a default value if I reload my form to be edited.  How can I have multiple default values for an `HTML.ListBox`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 @Html.ListBoxFor(m => Model.Value, new MultiSelectList(Model.DefaultValues, Model.EditValues))
```